# JSON: Passing two JSON object back in response vs. passing single JSON object with a flag to identify differences

Tags: jquery, json

We have two types of list that we need to pass from server to the client, one is list of popular cities and the other is list of non-popular cities.

The first option we have is to send back different json objects separately for popular and non popular cities like:

```
{
    "Cities": {
        "PopularCities": [
            {"id":1, "name":"PopularCity1"},
            {"id":2, "name":"PopularCity2"}
        ],
        "NonPopularCities": [
            {"id":3, "name":"NonPopularCity1"},
            {"id":4, "name":"NonPopularCity2"}
        ]
    }
}
```

OR

Fetching all cities in same JSON and using flag to distinguish popular and non-popular, for example:

```
{
    "Cities": {
            {"id":1, "name":"PopularCity1", "isPopular": true},
            {"id":2, "name":"PopularCity2", "isPopular": true}
            {"id":3, "name":"NonPopularCity3", "isPopular": false},
            {"id":4, "name":"NonPopularCity4", "isPopular": false}
    }
}
```

Which is better approach?

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite ambiguous , as both the approaches needs to be evaluated before used. If we go by design pattern, the key is expected to be name of meta data and value as required. So, the approach 1 shall look like

```
{"Cities": [{
    "type":"Popular Cities",
    "cityList" :[
        {"id":1, "name":"PopularCity1"},
        {"id":2, "name":"PopularCity2"}
    ]},
   {"type":"Some Other Cities",
    "cityList" :[
        {"id":1, "name":"SomePopularCity1"},
        {"id":2, "name":"SomePopularCity2"}
    ]},
   {"type":"Non Popular Cities",
    "cityList" :[
        {"id":1, "name":"NonPopularCity1"},
        {"id":2, "name":"NonPopularCity2"}
    ]}
]}
```

Where as the second approach seems to use flag variable which will again compute each time for filtering which doesn't seems to be of a good idea.